# is ggtsdisplay in forecast broken

Tags: r, ggplot2, updates

I'm using `R` version 3.3.2 with `ggplot2_2.2.0` and `forecast_7.3` (see below for full `sessionInfo()`). After my most recent update I'm having some issues with `ggtsdisplay()`. It's as it's not plotting the ACF, `ggAcf()`, and PACF, `ggPacf()` plots despite both `ggAcf()` and `ggPacf()` works separately (also code below),

What I'm getting now (after my most recent update),
[image: What I'm getting now]

What I got before my update,
[image: What I got before]

```
# install.packages(c("forecast", "zoo", "ggplot2"))
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
ggtsdisplay(mdeaths)
# sessionInfo()

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X Mavericks 10.9.5

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.2.0     forecast_7.3      timeDate_3012.100 zoo_1.7-13       
[5] colorout_1.1-2   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.8      quadprog_1.5-5   lattice_0.20-34  assertthat_0.1  
 [5] grid_3.3.2       plyr_1.8.4       gtable_0.2.0     scales_0.4.1    
 [9] lazyeval_0.2.0   tseries_0.10-35  fracdiff_1.4-2   labeling_0.3    
[13] tools_3.3.2      munsell_0.4.3    parallel_3.3.2   colorspace_1.3-1
[17] nnet_7.3-12      tibble_1.2
```

Comment: It worked for me with ``R 3.3.2``, ``forecast 7.3`` and ``ggplot2 2.1.0``, but no longer with ``ggplot2 2.2.0``. The problem might be in ``ggplot2`` and not in ``forecast``. What is weird is that `ggAcf` and `ggPacf` still work with ``ggplot2 2.2.0``

Comment: @etienne, I too got both `ggAcf` and `ggPacf` to work separately, which also seem odd to me. I also get the `ggAcf` in the `ggtsdisplay` if I add , `plot.type` eiher `partial`, `scatter`, or `spectrum`. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: @etienne I also rolled back to `ggplot2 2.1.0` from `ggplot2 2.2.0` (on Windows with R 3.3.2) and was able to recover the original (non-buggy) behavior, as desired. Thx!

Comment: It works with ggplot2 2.2.1 and forecast 7.4 (on github). I'll be pushing a new version of forecast to CRAN in next couple of weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same result with ggplot 2.1.0. Type the function name and notice from the parameters at the top of hte function that "partial" is the default plot "type". So this is the set of function calls:

```
if (plot.type == "partial") {
        lastplot <- ggPacf(x, lag.max = lag.max, na.action = na.action) + 
            ggplot2::ggtitle(NULL)
        acfplotrange <- ggplot2::ggplot_build(acfplot)$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range
        pacfplotrange <- ggplot2::ggplot_build(lastplot)$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range
        yrange <- range(c(acfplotrange, pacfplotrange))
        acfplot <- acfplot + ggplot2::ylim(yrange)
        lastplot <- lastplot + ggplot2::ylim(yrange)
}
```

Updating to ggplot2 to 2.2.0 gave the same results on  a Mac running 3.3.1. So you need to read the NEWS file for ggplot2 and see if there were any announced changes to `ggplot_build`. Which I tried to find and failed. Also tried the http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org website which has no announcements or links to changes that I could find. So I guess you need to send bug reports to both the maintainers of `ggplot2` and `forecast`.

```
> maintainer('ggplot2')
[1] "Hadley Wickham <hadley@rstudio.com>"
> maintainer('forecast')
[1] "Rob Hyndman <Rob.Hyndman@monash.edu>"
```

Do remember to include this sort of information:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 Patched (2016-08-17 r71112)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan (10.11.6)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grDevices utils     datasets  graphics  stats     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forecast_7.3      timeDate_3012.100 zoo_1.7-13        rms_4.5-0        
 [5] SparseM_1.7       Hmisc_3.17-4      ggplot2_2.2.0     Formula_1.2-1    
 [9] survival_2.40-1   sos_1.3-9         brew_1.0-6        lattice_0.20-33  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.7         RColorBrewer_1.1-2  plyr_1.8.4         
 [4] tseries_0.10-35     tools_3.3.1         rpart_4.1-10       
 [7] tibble_1.2          polspline_1.1.12    gtable_0.2.0       
[10] nlme_3.1-128        Matrix_1.2-6        parallel_3.3.1     
[13] mvtnorm_1.0-5       gridExtra_2.2.1     cluster_2.0.4      
[16] MatrixModels_0.4-1  grid_3.3.1          nnet_7.3-12        
[19] data.table_1.9.6    foreign_0.8-66      multcomp_1.4-6     
[22] latticeExtra_0.6-28 TH.data_1.0-7       scales_0.4.1       
[25] codetools_0.2-14    splines_3.3.1       MASS_7.3-45        
[28] assertthat_0.1      colorspace_1.2-6    fracdiff_1.4-2     
[31] labeling_0.3        quadprog_1.5-5      quantreg_5.26      
[34] sandwich_2.3-4      acepack_1.3-3.3     lazyeval_0.2.0     
[37] munsell_0.4.3       chron_2.3-47
```

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive response, I am very impressed. I have taken note and will go through the same steps the next time I get stuck.  I have added the full  `sessionInfo()` to my post. What is (extra) odd is that both `ggAcf` and `ggPacf` to work separately (see discussion with @etienne above).